# How to use http post method to call php webservice in android?

Tags: android, web-services, httpresponse

I'm calling php webservice through http post method. I'm sending the request in the proper way, but when responce comes, it is not giving me response.

That's what I have:

```
org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@4057f498
```

Help me, please.

Comment: Awful grammar. Fixed that. Please, give more attention to the way you're asking the questions.

Comment: Exactly duplicate question of yours. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5893543/614807

Comment: please check your question you asked before this . There i update my andwer for HttpPost Request. Please follow my answer it is works.

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal responce. What you need to get the information is to call a method:

```
responce.getEntity()
```

Read more [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicHttpResponse.html).

Answer (score 1):

HI Mehul,

Please pass your httpConnection object's getInputStream in this function it will return the response in String.

### Example

```
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(Your Url);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", your value to pass on server));
DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

InputStream inStream = entity.getContent();
```

Now Pass this inStream into function it will return the Message of your response.

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
{
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   String line = null;
   try 
   {
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
       {
           sb.append(line + "\n");
       }
   } 
   catch (IOException e) 
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } 
   finally 
   {
       try 
       {
           is.close();
       } 
       catch (IOException e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   return sb.toString();
```

}

Comment: ye dude finally get response in xml.your idea has done my work.thnks very much

Comment: if it is really helpful to you then please mark my answer as right,so other people can see it and use it .

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your `org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@4057fb48` is called `response`.
To retrieve the data from the HttpResponse, you need:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
final InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
```

You handle this `InputStream` depending on what kind of data it contains.

If you need the `String` value of the response entity:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
final String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to do something similar to the following.

```
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
  StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
  if (status.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
  {
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String responseBody = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
    ...
  }
```